# C match pattern with infinite input

Tags: c, input, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a program that receives input infinitely and whenever an input sequence matches a given pattern it should print that a match has been found and continue searching for other occurrences of the pattern
I managed just to code this

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(){
      char ch;
      char pattern[4]="1234";
      int i=0;
      while(1){
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        if(ch==pattern[i]){
          count+=1;
          i+=1;
        }
        //printf("%c",ch);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Help me solve the code

Comment: there is a problem with the code that when there is repetition of characters it does not work     for example 11234 does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from here, you got the idea.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(){
      char ch;
      char pattern[4]="1234";
      int i=0;
      while(1){
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        if(ch==pattern[i]){
          i+=1;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        if (i == 4) {
            printf("match found!\n");
            i = 0;
        }
        //printf("%c",ch);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I tried running the code but it didn't print match when i entered the pattern

Comment: That code ll not work properly. Just change scanf line to `scanf(" %c",&ch);`.
Classic problem of scanf eating enter.

Comment: @shubhamjohar you realize you can only enter 1 character at a time,, so if you're looking for "pattern" matching beyond 1 character you're going to have to buffer the input one character at a time or save your input as a string instead.

Comment: @yano, It's a state machine, when the first character of the pattern is matched, i is increment, then when the second, and so on. Resets to zero when a match is not found.  No need for the string buffer.

Comment: @jwdonahue I see that in the code.. just doesn't seem to match the OP's text description of desired behavior, particularly the "... continue searching for other occurrences of the pattern" part.

Comment: @yano, it's a while(1) loop, it runs until the program is killed.